# In what context or situation (if any) would the words "try to see me" make sense?

Tags: expressions, conversation

If there is such possible situation, please, describe it.

Please don't insert any punctuation between those words and keep their order intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"try to see me" could mean "try to meet with me for a few minutes", as in "try to see me next time you're in the office."

It could also be the literal meaning: "I'm testing a video camera, stand there and try to see me."

Comment: @Carmy: So, in case with camera, the phrase "try to see me" would mean "try to look at me" or "try to face the camera" (while the camera is, of course, being held by the one who is denoted by pronoun "me" here) right?

Comment: @brilliant: It's the other way round. you're holding the camera, "me" denotes the person who should be seen through the camera.

Comment: @Carmy: Aaaah! I got it. It's just so funny that at first I understood you perfectly the other way around! :)

Answer (score 1):

The phrase could also be used by a doctor to a patient:

> Try to see me again next month.

This would be a suggestion for the patient to come back and speak with the doctor next month.

Answer (score 0):

This [Yahoo question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100522014040AAgma0V) seems to provide a good example, as in "try to renew a relationship":

"Why does my ex try to see me so soon after breaking up?"

The other meaning would be to "try to see me" (as I truly am), like in the ["Try to see me" song from the Legion Within](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Legion_Within%3aTry_To_See_Me).

Answer (score 0):

One of the meaning of *to see* is *meet someone one knows, socially or by chance*.

> I went to see Caroline.
>   I saw Colin last night.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the Flash was trying to impress a girl he could say: "I'm gonna move from the left side of the room, to the right. Try to see me.".